# Kernel Density Estimate (Probability Density Function) is wrong?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, histogram, kernel-density

I've created a histogram to show the density of the age at which serial killers first killed and have tried to superimpose a probability density function on this. However, when I use the geom_density() function in ggplot2, I get a density function that looks far too small (area<1). What is strange is that by changing the bin width of the histogram, the density function also changes (the smaller the bin width, the seemingly better fitting the density function. I was wondering if anyone had some guidance to make this function fit better and its area is so far below 1?

```
    #Histograms for Age of First Kill: 
library(ggplot2)
AFKH <- ggplot(df, aes(AgeFirstKill,fill = cut(AgeFirstKill, 100))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)), show.legend = FALSE, binwidth = 3) + # density wasn't working, so had to use the ..count/../sum(..count..)
  scale_fill_discrete(h = c(200, 10), c = 100, l = 60) + # c =, for color, and l = for brightness, the #h = c() changes the color gradient
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=22,face="bold"), 
        plot.title = element_text(size=30, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size=14),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=14)) +
  labs(title = "Age of First kill",x = "Age of First Kill", y = "Density")+
  geom_density(aes(AgeFirstKill, y = ..density..), alpha = 0.7, fill = "white",lwd =1, stat = "density")
AFKH
```

[image: binwidth = 1]

[image: bindwidth =3]

Comment: The histogram is wrong in the second plot, not the desity: the height of the columns is far too great. The density seems to be ok, because it is identical to the first plot.

Comment: can we have a [mcve] please?  if you want the histogram and the density to match you should probably use `..density..`, which accounts for bin width as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have your data set, so let's make one that's reasonably close to it:

```r
set.seed(3)
df <- data.frame(AgeFirstKill = rgamma(100, 3, 0.2) + 10)
```

The first thing to notice is that the *density curve doesn't change*. Look carefully at the y axis on your plot. You will notice that the peak of the density curve doesn't change, but remains at about 0.06. It's the height of the histogram bars that change, and the y axis changes accordingly.

The reason for this is that you aren't dividing the height of the histogram bars by their width to preserve their area. Your y aesthetic should be `..count../sum(..count..)/binwidth` to keep this constant.

To show this, let's wrap your plotting code in a function that allows you to specify the bin width but also takes the binwidth into account when plotting:

```r
draw_it <- function(bw) {
  ggplot(df, aes(AgeFirstKill,fill = cut(AgeFirstKill, 100))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)/bw), show.legend = FALSE, 
                 binwidth = bw) +
  scale_fill_discrete(h = c(200, 10), c = 100, l = 60) + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=22,face="bold"), 
        plot.title = element_text(size=30, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size=14),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=14)) +
  labs(title = "Age of First kill",x = "Age of First Kill", y = "Density") +
  geom_density(aes(AgeFirstKill, y = ..density..), alpha = 0.7, 
               fill = "white",lwd =1, stat = "density")
}
```

And now we can do:

```r
draw_it(bw = 1)
```

[image]

```r
draw_it(bw = 3)
```

[image]

```r
draw_it(bw = 7)
```

[image]

Comment: I think `..density..` might be equivalent to `..count../sum(..count..)/binwidth` ...

Comment: @BenBolker I think that's right, but the OP said that `..density..` didn't work for them

Comment: Could also use the newer `after_stat(ndensity)` instead of `..density..`

Comment: @Phil I think the problem is with the fill scale that the OP is using. Neither `..density..` , `stat(density)` nor `after_stat(density)` will preserve the color scheme here. This is easy to test with my code. If you can think of a way to use `after_stat(density)` and preserve the fill colors it would be good to see it.

Comment: I think the fill colours are a bad idea anyway :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Allan! this helped a great deal, and thanks to everyone else's responses, I'll make sure to give them a go! :)